# Transferring media with posts while moving wordpress blog to another server

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to  move a wordpress blog from one server to another server. I am able to move  the posts and user accounts. I am able to move the media uploaded by the users but they are no longer linked to the posts. How can move the media with the posts without losing the linking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the media attachments to be linked to your Posts, you need to migrate all of the **wp_posts** table also, not only the parts of it. As each attachment is actually linked by a parent_post field with other posts.

Also, you can use the [WordPress Importer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/) plugin to import the posts. By importing the posts, the attachments will be downloaded in the new server and linked with the posts. But if you have a lot of post and media files, that would take time.

Answer (score 0):

Export tool

You can export your posts, pages, comments, custom fields, categories, and tags from one WordPress website to another website by creating an XML file.

Download and save this XML file to your computer .and by using import function in other WordPress websites you can import XML file.

To open Export tool go to Dashboard> Tools > Export.

Now click on an Export button it will open a new window.

what_to_export

There you can see three options

All content – By using this option you can export all content of website including posts, pages, comments, custom fields etc.

Posts or Pages– By next two options you can export Posts or Pages content. On selecting Posts or Page option, it will open a new window with different options like authors name, date range, and status. Hence by using these options, you can select your desired pages or posts that you want to export.

download XML FILE

After doing all settings click on Download Export File. An XML file will automatically start downloading to your computer.
Import tool

You can import posts, page or comments or other content from another WordPress.com or WordPress.org blog or site. To open import tool go to Dashboard > Tools > Import.

By default, WordPress does not provide import functionality.  Hence to get this feature you have to install a Plugin.

On clicking on import .it will open a new window where you can choose a plugin according to your need from the list of plugins.

import_tool

```
WordPress importer- is used for Import posts, comments, custom fields, pages, and categories from a WordPress export file.
```

Now just click on WordPress out of all plugins. It will release a new window .where you click on install now button to install the WordPress importer.

install_importer

Now activate this plugins .after activation it will open a new tab from where you can choose your exported XML file (created by using the export tool) from your computer.

choose_XML_file

Now click on upload and import XML file. It will automatically add your exported content to your website and that’s it.

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You need to export your posts from your old site, import them to the new site and then redirect the post to their new location.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by packaging up your Files.
Well if you simply If you simply drag and drop files from one server to another using a GUI interface, chances are good that the GUI will omit hidden files such as the vital .htaccess file. Besides, transferring hundreds of files via FTP can take a long time because each file must often undergo some sort of authentication; in other words copying over a hundred 1 megabyte files takes a lot longer than copying over a single 100 megabyte file.

On a UNIX style system, you can create a compressed file using the tar command:

tar -czf /path/to/backups/modx_revo_site.tar.gz /path/to/modx_doc_root/

Once you arrive on the other end, it's good to put the zipped file into its own directory before you extract it. The idea here is that if it explodes, it's easier to clean up the mess if it's contained in its own directory.

On a UNIX style system, you can unpackage a .tar.gz file using the following commands from a command line:

gunzip modx_revo_site.tar.gz
tar xvf modx_revo_site.tar

Once you've extracted the files, you can move the whole directory into the correct place. Again, be careful about moving files in bulk: you might inadvertently forget to copy those hidden files. It's better to rename or move the containing directory instead.

Detailed explanation can be found under: https://docs.modx.com/revolution/2.x/administering-your-site/moving-your-site-to-a-new-server

Answer (score 0):

Important is, that you use a permanent redirect not a temporary redirect. This will decrease the SEO Power over time. The Temporary Redirect redirect status response code indicates that the resource requested has been temporarily moved to the URL given by the Location headers.

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree with the above said methods. Make sure to include all media and copy the authorizations as well. I had some issues a while ago when I tried to move my content on another server an totally forgot about the authorizations...